# Use function in twig's translation

Tags: formatting, symfony, translation, twig

i have translation of string containing date.

```
{% trans with {'%date%': lastAcceptedDate } from "translations" %}createdBefore%date%notAccepted{% endtrans %}
```

Now i would like to format the date. Probably by date function. Something like following in PHP

```
__( 'createdBefore%date%notAccepted', 
    array(
        '%date%' => (new DateTime($lastAcceptedDate))->format('d.m. Y')
    )
);
```

This is definitely not working or optimal code. It's just another form of explanation of what i want to achieve.

I found i can do it in twig with normal string like so

```
{{ lastAcceptedDate | date("d.m. Y") }}
```

but i am unable to find how to do it in twig's translation tag.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

```
{% trans with {'%date%': (lastAcceptedDate | date("d.m. Y")) } from "translations" %}createdBefore%date%notAccepted{% endtrans %}
```

If it works maybe the round parenthesis are not even needed!